# Can't create a virtual environment in the Google Drive folder

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, drive

I'm using Google Drive to keep a copy of my code projects in case my computer dies (I'm also using GitHub, but not on some private projects).

However, when I try to create a virtual environment using `virtualenv`, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\users\fchatter\google drive> virtualenv env
New python executable in C:\users\fchatter\google drive\env\Scripts\python.exe
ERROR: The executable "C:\users\fchatter\google drive\env\Scripts\python.exe" could not be run: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Things I've tried:

- I thought it was because the path to the venv included blank spaces, but the command works in other paths with blank spaces. I also tried installing the win32api library, as recommended in the `virtualenv` docs, but it didn't work.
- running the PowerShell as an administrator.

Any ideas on how to solve this? My workaround at the moment is to create the venv outside of the Google Drive, which works but is inconvenient.

Comment: Have you checked the permission settings for your `python.exe`? If for whatever reason your user account does not have read/execute privileges it won't work, as the error indicates.

Comment: If you're in need of private repositories, check Bitbucket rathen than using Google Drive. They offer private repos in their free plan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't set up a virtual env in a cloud synced folder, nor should you run a python script from such a folder. It's a bad idea. They are not meant for version control.

I suggest you stick to `git` for version control.

Comment: That does not provide an answer. The question is not how to set up the project according to best practice, it's to get virtualenv to work in Google Drive.

The reason it fails is because there is a space in the path, and virtualenv does not support that. This has nothing to do with Google Drive.

Comment: this still the case? seems to after all these years

Answer (score 1):

After running into the same issue and playing with it for several hours, it doesn't seem possible.  It has nothing to do with spaces in file/folder names.  I've tested that.  It seems that Google Drive Stream perform some action to the file/folder after a period of time that makes python loose its path the files.  For instance, you can take clone a python module into a Google Drive Stream folder, do a "pip install -e ./", and it will work in the virtevn for a few minutes, for instance importing it into a python shell.  But after a few minutes you can no longer import the module.  I suspect that Google Drive Stream is simply not fully compatible with all filesystem system calls, one of which is being used by python.